# Webpack4 handlebars project folder hyphen issue

Tags: webpack, handlebars.js

I've setup a github repo for a basic Webpack + Handlebars boilerplate: https://github.com/PixelRocket-Shop/boilerplate-html. When you download/clone the repo, the project root folder is named "boilerplate-html-main". If you then run "npm install" followed by "npm start", webpack dev server doesn't work. Nor does compiling the dist folder by running "npm run build".

I think the issue is the root folder name containing hyphens - if I change the root folder from "boilerplate-html-main" to "test", everything works fine. Does anyone have an idea why hyphens in the project folder name would cause either Webpack or Handlebars to break?

Comment: I was able to download, npm install and npm start.
No issues whatsoever!

Comment: Even npm run build compolted and created assets and src folders in dist.
You may have run into some other issue. Try re-install:
1. Remove node_modules
2. Remove package-lock.json
3. run npm cache clear -f
4. npm install
5. npm start

Comment: that's so weird. I'm on a Mac - are you on a Windows machine by any chance?

Comment: yeah, I am on windows 10

Comment: Your welcome!
Could you share error log you get in mac?

Comment: I don't get an error. All I get is the listing directory (in my browser). If I compile my dist folder, then I see a part of the root folder's name inside the dist folder. So what should be: dist/index.html is instead: dist/-main/index.html. That's how I figured out the hyphens in the root folder were causing the issue.

Comment: Can you try adding below to your webpack config?
{
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
target: 'node'
}
https://v4.webpack.js.org/configuration/target/#target
https://v4.webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputpath

Comment: Nope, same issue. I've narrowed down the issue to line 147: output: path.join(process.cwd(), 'dist', '[path]', '[name].html'). That [path] value is where things are breaking down. If I remove it, the correct HTML files are output inside my dist folder. But my {{webRoot}} handlebars helper is then incorrect. I can fix that easily enough, so I've done that for now. But I'd love to know why this is happening.